# How to set list permissions based on Content Approval Status?

Tags: 2010, list, permissions

I'm trying to give all users access to propose new items for my lists, but I don't want anyone other than Approvers to have access to delete or reject items. I was able to figure out how to set up Approvers with "Require content approval" set to "yes" on each list. I have created custom entry form for people to use when submitting new items and another form to review their submissions. What I need to do is to prevent users from deleting or modifying items that they did not create and delete or modify their own items that have been approved.

When I give people "Read" access they can see my lists but can not use entry form.
When I give people "Contribute" access they can submit new items but can also delete any items.

Is there a way to have permission that falls in between the Read and Contribute?

Update:
Need to make sure that users can only edit their own items that are marked Approval Status="Pending or Rejected". Items that are marked Approval Status="Approved" can only be edited or deleted by select group. 

note: *it is fine if there is nothing out the box, I just want to know if it can be achieved and how much customization I would need to do to justify the time to spend on this to management. They might decide that it is not important to them based on time constrain.*

Running SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can easily do that by creating a "Custom Permission Level". Basically you can select what all permissions will this level have. Then you can assign this permission level to a group and start adding people to it. The people in the group will have all the permission you specified in the Custom Permission Level. Have a look here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239(v=office.14).aspx

**Update:**

For making sure that users can edit and delete their own items, do the following:

Go to List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Item Level Permissions -> Create and Edit Access -> and select "Create items and edit items that were created by the user"

Comment: Looks like my sharepoint administrator did not give me access to create new permissions levels on my site. When I click on Permission Levels I don't have toolbar to Add a Permission Level. It just says "This web site inherits permissions levels from parent Web site." I guess I will need to get my administrator involved.

Thanks so much for quick response.

Comment: Looks like you missed the second part of my question:
Looking at List Permissions in Permission levels I don't see anything that refers to Content Approval? How can I make sure that users only can edit and delete their own items before it has been approved?

Comment: You can break permission inheritance so that the site no longer inherits from the parent.

Comment: @SaUce please check the update for answer to your second question.

Comment: Thanks for update. But what I'm really looking for is to base permissions around "Approved","Rejected" and "Pending "Status". I only want specific group of people to be able to modify and delete items that are marked as "Approved" everyone else can edit delete their own items that are marked "Pending or Rejected"